# multiple definition of `login::GetEventHashTable() const'

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

i got this error
multiple definition of `login::GetEventHashTable() const'
can anybody tell me, when it occour...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as my experience said, it is happening because of multiplicity of same header files
write

## ifndef HANDLER_H_

## define HANDLER_H_

at the top(u can change the header file name, i have handler.h
and

## endif

at the bottom of any header file

Answer (score 0):

Please share code snippet, as rough guess, did you forget semi colon ; in at the end of class declaration in header file? like

class abc
{

}; --> here

Answer (score 0):

Multiple definitions often occur when multiple copies of an include file are included.  This problem can be most easily avoided by adding

```
#pragma once
```

at the top of every include file.